# Fail to fill in a triangular part of my matrix with a vector: warning about length

Tags: r, matrix

I have a vector to be filled into a lower triangular part of a matrix. But I have got a warning message.

```
par1 <-  0.5:7
par1 <- sample(par1, 496, replace = T)
par11 <- matrix(0, 32, 32)
par11[lower.tri(par11, diag = TRUE)] <- par1

Warning message:
In par11[lower.tri(par11, diag = TRUE)] <- par1 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

The dimension of my matrix is `32`, so I should have `496` non-zero elements. where is my mistake?

Comment: When you add the argument `diag = T` then the length changes from being 496 to 496+32=528. Thus unequal vectors. You not use diag=T or you may sample 528

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A triangular part (without main diagonal) in an `N x N` matrix has `N x (N - 1) / 2` elements. If including main diagonal, there are `N x (N + 1) / 2`.